# Covariance matrix of regularized likelihood

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, regularization, covariance-matrix

My question is how to estimate the covariance matrix of parameters in a regularized likelihood maximization.
Lets assume we have constructed some negative log-likelihood with a set of parameters and a regularisation term with a regularisation constant $\tau \geq 0$.
$$
\phi(\vec{\mu}) = -\log p(X|\vec{\mu}) - \tau S(\vec{\mu})
$$
Minimizing this w.r.t. $\vec{\mu}$ will give estimators $\hat{\vec{\mu}}$.
Would the inverse of the hessian of this function still be the covariance matrix
$$
\mathcal{H}^{ij}(\hat{\vec{\mu}}) = \frac{\partial^{2}\phi(\vec{\mu})}{\partial\mu_{i}\partial\mu_{j}}\Bigg|_{\vec{\mu}=\hat{\vec{\mu}}} = (\Sigma_{\vec{\mu}}^{ij})^{-1}
$$
$$
\Sigma_{\vec{\mu}} = (\mathcal{H}(\hat{\vec{\mu}}))^{-1}
$$
or is that relation no longer valid with the added regularisation term? If not, what are alternative ways to estimate the covariance matrix in this case?